# Formulario de contacto JAMStack y cuentas de correo en hosting al estilo Vercel, Netlify o Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, next.js, nodemailer

hice esta pregunta en otros lugares pero parece ser imposible una respuesta.
Como se logra en JAMStack (React.js o Next.js) hacer un formulario de contacto como si se puede hacer, y de manera tan fácil (y con diferentes plugins), en Wordpress o cms basados en php.
Además los hosting de estos cms ofrecen la posibilidad de crear numerosas cuentas de correo (usuarios), por que eso no existe en JAMStack???
No busco servicio de endpoints externos como formsubmit.co o https://kwesforms.com/ que dan solo 100 envíos por día en versión gratuita, si no son al rededor de 25 dólares mensuales. Hay que tener en cuenta que un hosting para Wordpress (con todo el servicio de cuentas de correo electrónico) ronda los 70 dólares anuales.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Desea persistir esta información ?